# Fast traverse through lxml tree by avoiding specific branch

Tags: python, lxml

Suppose I have an etree as following:

```
my_data.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <country name="Liechtenstein" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Singapore" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
  </country>
  <ethnicity xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
    <malay>
      <holidays>
        <ramadan>Yes</ramadan>
      </holidays>
    </malay>
  </ethnicity>
</data>
```

Parsing:

```
xtree = etree.parse('my_data.xml')
xroot = xtree.getroot()
```

I want to traverse through the tree and do stuff to all branches, except certain brances. In this example, I want to exclude the `ethnicity` branch:

```
node_to_exclude = xroot.xpath('.//*[local-name()="ethnicity"]')
exclude_path = xtree.getelementpath(node_to_exclude[0])

for element in xroot.iter('*'):
   if exclude_path not in xtree.getelementpath(element ):
      ...do stuff...
```

But this will still traverse through the entire tree. Is there any better / faster way than this (i.e. ignore the entire `ethnicity` branch together)? I m looking for a syntactical solution, not a recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath can do this for you

```
for element in xroot.xpath('.//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[local-name()="ethnicity"])]'):
    # ...do stuff...
```

It might - or might not, measure it - improve performance to specify which ancestor you mean. For example, if `<ethnicity xmlns="...">` always is a child of the top-level element, i.e. "the penultimate ancestor", you could do this:

```
for element in xroot.xpath('.//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[last()-1][local-name()="ethnicity"])]'):
    # ...do stuff...
```

Of course you can also do something like:

```
for child in xroot.getchildren()
    if 'ethnicity' in child.tag:
        continue
    for element in child.xpath('//*'):
        # ...do stuff...
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the ```ancestor-or-self``` solution !

Comment: @TristanTran it's elegant, but it will probably not be the fastest you can get, because XPath will check every ancestor of every element. If you know your document structure, there are better ways, such as the last suggestion.